# How subtract two list of different lengths?

Tags: python

I have two lists:

```py
a=[[41,25,98,20],[14,74,52],[98,45,49,78,26]]
b=[[10],[20],[30]]
```

and I'd like to subtract these lists and get the result:

```py
c=[[31,15,88,10],[-6,54,32],[68,15,19,48,-4]]
```

I'm a beginner in python programming, this examples is very difficult for me.

Maybe there'll be someone to solve my problem.
Please help me.

Comment: What have you tried? What specifically do you need help with?

Answer (score 3):

Making some assumptions about what shape `a` and `b` are in:

```
a = [[41, 25, 98, 20], [14, 74, 52], [98, 45, 49, 78, 26]]
b = [[10], [20], [30]]

def subtract_lists(a, b):
    return [[i - j for i in l] for l, (j,) in zip(a, b)]

print(subtract_lists(a, b))
```

giving the result

```
[[31, 15, 88, 10], [-6, 54, 32], [68, 15, 19, 48, -4]]
```

Comment: That was it , Thanks for your answer